# How to create horizontal RecyclerView which shows dots then screen space is full?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView and layout for list item.
How to create horizontal RecyclerView without scrolling, but then width of screen is full, will shows dots or something else like this
[image]

set list to RecyclerView adapter

```
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(FragmentComponentManager.findActivity(context), itemList);     
holder.labelListView.setAdapter(labelRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/label_list"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```